How to apply a video texture to a MaterialInstance in AR using a SurfaceTexture stream?
I am new to AR, trying to apply video texture to materialInstance by creating a surfaceTexture stream and using this stream to create the videoTexture , surfaceTexture is being updated by a video with MediaPlayer.
For my implementation I am getting "stream has not been initialized" error.
How can this be corrected?
Is there any other way to build and add videoTexture to materialInstance in sceneview:2.2.0?
private fun applyVideoTexture(
    context: Context,
    engine: Engine,
    materialInstance: MaterialInstance
) {
    try {
       
        val surfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(1) 

        val stream =  Stream.Builder()
            .stream(surfaceTexture) 
            .build(engine)
        

        
        val videoTexture = VideoTexture.Builder()
            .build(engine)
        videoTexture.setExternalStream(engine, stream)  // Attach the Stream

        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.samp)
        mediaPlayer.setSurface(Surface(surfaceTexture)) 
        mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
        mediaPlayer.start()



        materialInstance.setParameter("texture", videoTexture, TextureSampler())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

